# OpenGL Fixed function shader implementation

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is there any wrapper which emulates the OpenGL ES 1.1 API on top of OpenGL ES 2.0? I was searching quite a bit but could not find any actual implementation.

Comment: Although I cannot point to such a wrapper, I suggest you try to write such a wrapper yourself, just for training. Writing shaders to emulate the fixed-function pipeline is a wonderful excercise to learn more about how the fixed-function concepts really work, until you realize, that emulating the fixed-function OpenGL ES 1.1 API is not the most flexible or efficient way to use OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: If you have a look at the Opengl ES 2.0 Programming Guide, they try to implement parts of the fixed-function pipeline. As can quickly be seen , this is no simple task.

I do not really se why you want this - why not just use OpenGL ES 1.1. I do not know of any 2.0 GPU that do not also support 1.1

Comment: WebGL is only supporting OpenGL Es 2.0. And I have a whole bunch of code I need to port from OpenGL ES 1.1 to 2.0. Instead of changing huge parts of code I'd gradually switch from an ES 1.1 emulation to 2.0 so I can run tests and see when something breaks.

Comment: So is this for a particular platform? For example, would a C solution be sufficient (though you couldn't use it for a Dalvik app on Android for example), or even a closed source proprietary solution that was for just the iPhone or whatever?

Comment: C would be fine. Closed source not since it has to work on a whole bunch of platforms (and most CS does not). I currently started writing it in C++ though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently investigating same question, just stumbled upon this project: https://github.com/p3/regal#readme (OpenGL portability layer for OpenGL 2.x, 3.x, 4.x, Core contexts and ES 2.0). Only going to try it myself, but after reading the article http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/177233/Indepth_Bringing_Regal_OpenGL_to_Native_Client.php, I believe this library may be solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/gles2-bc/

this aims to emulate ES 1.1 with ES 2.0 shaders, not used it myself but will be doing!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at JOGL.

There are some packages about emulation the fixed pipeline from GLES 1.0 using the GLES 2.0:

```
package javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc;
package com.jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc;   
package jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc;
```

Javadoc from the jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc.FixedFuncImpl class;

```
Composable pipeline, implementing the interface javax.media.opengl.GL2ES1
Each method follows the call graph:
* call prolog jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc.FixedFuncHook if available 
* call downstream javax.media.opengl.GL2ES2 if available and if no call to jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc.FixedFuncHook is made 

* Interface javax.media.opengl.GL2ES1 
* Prolog jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.fixedfunc.FixedFuncHook 
* Downstream javax.media.opengl.GL2ES2 

Sample code which installs this pipeline: 
     GL gl = drawable.setGL( new FixedFuncImpl( drawable.getGL().getGL2ES2(), new FixedFuncHook( drawable.getGL().getGL2ES2() ) ) );
```

Besides, take a look at "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide" (Aaftab Munshi at alli.). There are some shaders examples about emulation of GLES 1.0 FFP.

Answer (score 2):

you might like this tutorial: [Recreating OpenGL's Fixed Function Pipeline using Cg](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030005605/http://www.codesampler.com/oglsrc/oglsrc_11.htm#ogl_cg_fixed_function). It is in CG, but that is rather similar to GLSL, with a few tweaks, one could surely turn it into a shader that would mimic fixed-function pipeline on Android.

As for the other deprecated functions, such as glVertex*(), i would advise against it (it was deprecated for a reason). If, on the other hand, one needed to port some software from ES 1 to ES 2, it should not be very hard to write a wrapper even on that.